# Is there any method to run example.exe C# desktop application through double click in Mac OS X 10.4.8?

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I can run example.exe from Terminal( "mono example.exe").And I can not do this through "Open With" option because it doesn't get mono application type to choose it.
How can I do it double clickable?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to build a Mac OSX "Bundle" to do this.  There is a fantastic article written that demonstrates this:

http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app

Answer (score 1):

For the quick and dirty method, you want to use [macpack](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications#macpack_.28Mac_OS_X_only.29).

BTW, it says Cocoa# only, but I've used it with WinForms and GTK# apps as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to [create an app bundle](http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app).